# Why is my NavBar's background not covering the last menu item?

Tags: css

Something on my website is bothering me.
The last menu item of my Navbar is outside it's container's background:

[image]

Here is how my CSS looks like:

```
.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    align-items: space-evenly;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;
    background: #242222;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  .nav-links:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #242424;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .navbar-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(25%, 50%);
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #242424;
    transition: 250ms;
  }
}
```

and HTML generated by a React component looks like this:

```
<>
  <nav className='navbar'>
    <div className='navbar-container'>
      <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
        LOGO
      </Link>
      <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
        <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
      </div>
      <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <HashLink to='/#wherewefly' onClick={closeMobileMenu} className='nav-links'>
            Where we fly
          </HashLink>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <Link
            to='/services'
            className='nav-links'
            onClick={closeMobileMenu}
          >
            Promotions
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <Link
            to='/products'
            className='nav-links'
            onClick={closeMobileMenu}
          >
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      {button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>LOGIN</Button>}
    </div>
  </nav>
</>
```

How can I make the last menu item (Contact) be covered by the black background too?

I have tried changing the height but the menu items "follow" and are aligned to the bottom. I can't find out how to change it though.

Edited: Picture has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove `height: 280px;`.**

You are using flex-box so you shouldn't be setting the height or width attributes. The idea is to allow the box to be flexible to it's contents.

If you want a fixed height you should be using `flex-basis` attribute.

---

**EXAMPLE**

I have had to convert your react to html to demonstrate but as you can see the code you provided works as expected. This would indicate the issue lies elsewhere in code you have not provided.

```css
.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  align-items: space-evenly;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: #242222;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-links {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #242424;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(25%, 50%);
}

.menu-icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-times {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.nav-links-mobile {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 80%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.nav-links-mobile:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #242424;
  transition: 250ms;
}
```

```html
<nav class='navbar'>
  <div clas='navbar-container'>
    <a class='navbar-logo'> LOGO
    </a>
    <div class='menu-icon'>
      <i class='fas fa-times' />
    </div>
    <ul class='nav-menu active'>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-links'> Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-links'>
          Where we fly
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-links'> Promotions
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-links'> Contact
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Button class='btn--outline'>LOGIN</Button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did and adjusted the top, however the Contact link is still outside the black background.

Comment: Try to use justify-content: flex-start; inseted of  align-content: flex-start; in .nav-menu.active selector ...

Comment: Thanks for the efforts and for the flex advice. I think something else might be messing the css (I have other css files in this project). I created a new li with an empty span and it worked (Although I am not proud of it :-p )

Answer (score -1):

Well, the height is fixed in the CSS, if you want it to take the height the content has you need to use "fit-content".

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do it?

Comment: Just do: `height: fit-content;` in your .nav-menu class.

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Blockquote

The issue could be the height of the nav-menu. please use min-hight instead. This may fix your issue

```
.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    align-items: space-evenly;
  }
```

Comment: min-height didn't do the trick :-(